# Why does MainActivity.this return null?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

MainActivity (outside OnCreate function):

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DatasheetActivity.class);
```

Manifest:

```xml
        <activity
            android:name=".DatasheetActivity"
            android:label="DatasheetActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I also tried `new Intent(this, DatasheetActivity.class)` to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just also declared the problem: I initialized Intent outside of OnCreate.
The solution is to declare the variable `Intent intent;` and then assign a newly created Intent within OnCreate and you could use it in other functions: `intent = new Intent(this, DatasheetActivity.class)`